# Is this wikipedia article about KNN contradicting itself regarding "non-parametric"?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, nonparametric, hyperparameter

I understood that `KNN` (`K-Nearest-Neighbors`) was non-parametric, after reading the beginning of the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm):

> In pattern recognition, the $k$-Nearest Neighbors algorithm (or $k$-NN for
>   short) is a non-parametric method used for...

But, then later in the article it talks of estimating the "parameters"??

> The best choice of $k$ depends upon the data; generally, larger values
>   of $k$ reduce the effect of noise on the classification,[5] but make
>   boundaries between classes less distinct.

Am I missing the difference between parameters and hyperparameters?  Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of similar questions on the distinction between parametric and non-parametric. (1) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46588/why-are-gaussian-process-models-called-non-parametric/46621#46621 (2) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103833/are-non-parametric-methods-well-defined (3) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185909/why-is-kernel-density-estimation-still-nonparametric-with-parametrized-kernel/185941#185941

Comment: short answer: non-parametric can been interpreted as **unfixed** number of parameters (or all possible solutions cannot be defined by a finite number of parameters) . So because the final number of parameters is determined by the data, it can be considered non-parametric.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm interested in this for the context of machine learning, (`random forest`, `kNN`, `SVM`, etc.)  So, two clarifications:  **fixed** for what - the function that your ML algorithm produces for predicting new labels/target variables?

Comment: @Candic3: the function that is produced is a function of various parameters. The question is: **before** seeing your data, do you know how many parameters are necessary to describe this function (or moreover, the model that the function uses to produce new predictions)?